# IOS/Objective-C: can't save CoreData values into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to save CoreData values into an array for later display it in a table view. But so far, the logs show me that the array is empty (null) though there is data in the application. I don't understand why this happens. Can somebody give me a help? Here's the code:

```
    @interface TableViewController ()

    @property (strong) NSMutableArray *locations;

    @end

    @implementation TableViewController

    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
        id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
            context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
        }
        return context;
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

      NSError *error;   

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Spot"];
        self.locations = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
         NSLog(@"%@ Places are: ", _locations);

        }
```

EDIT: the AppDelegate.m:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedDelegate {
    return (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
- ( NSURLSession * )getURLSession
{
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once( &onceToken,^{

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration =[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

    });

    return session;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:franciscocosta.net/lisbon-spots"]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[self getURLSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
    ^( NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error ){


    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        NSError *error;

    NSArray *mainLocations = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        for(NSDictionary *dict in mainLocations) {
            [Spot spotWithDict:dict];
                            }
                });
        }];

    [task resume];

     return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do you ignore the `error` parameter? And why is `locations` declared immutable but assigned mutable?

Comment: Ok, it's edited, but the log remains null...

Comment: You are still ignoring the error. Does it contain anything?

Comment: Just loged the error and it's also null...

Comment: Is `managedObjectContext` `nil`? Set a breakpoint and check the references?

Comment: yes, mNgedObjectContext is empty. How do I set a breakpoint? (sorry, i'm kind of new at this, I really apreciate your attention)

Comment: Sorry, this is very basic stuff. Use google and search **xcode breakpoint**, for example http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode. And you should know at design time if there is a `managedObjectContext` property in `AppDelegate`. The check for `respondsToSelector` is actually not needed.

Comment: context = [delegate managedObjectContext];-> i've inserted a breakpoint in this line

Comment: So when it stops at that break point, step over that line, and then look at the value of `context`.  Is it nil?  If so, you should probably post the code for `[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]` (or whatever your app delegate class is).

Comment: well I dont have managedObjectContext in my Appdelegate. Is that the reason for the problem?

Comment: and yes, the "return context" line is nil...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create the core data stack. Form a singleton? In this case pass the reference of the created managedObjectContext to a managedObjectContext property in your appDelegate.

May you take a look to the stack creation of [Marcus Zarra.](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/) Or Apple Core Data [Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1)